# How to open a window in a separate thread?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to do:

```
Window newWindow = new Window();
newWindow.Show();

while (true) 
{
    Console.Write("spin");
}
```

I.e., I'm doing an intensive calculation in main window, but this new window (where I'm trying to show a busy indicator with an animation) is not responding (it's frozen)...

So I tried to do:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Window newWindow = new Window();
    newWindow.Show();
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();

while (true) 
{
    Console.Write("spin");
}
```

But the new window is still frozen, etc. 
Anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Why not just perform your work on another thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't try to open a new Window in it's own thread.

Instead, push the computational work you're doing into a background thread, and leave the UI thread free.  The simplest option for this is typically to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).  It handles the marshaling of progress and completion back to the UI thread for you automatically.

However, you can do this yourself using threads or `Task`/`Task<T>`, as well.  Just remember to use the Dispatcher or a TaskScheduler created from the UI context for anything that will update the UI, such as progress notifcication.

Comment: the "computation work" is actually a new window that's being displayed (in addition to newWindow that is). I'm loading a new window which takes a while to load.

Comment: @foreyez: You can typically have the "new window" move the non-UI computations into a background thread, and avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: I think he is recommending put the work done in the New or Load method of the window in a new thread.  The window can then open and show a loading message (if in the load event)

Comment: @foreyez: It sounds like you're saying that the slow computational work is currently tightly coupled into the window creation routine.  Same advice applies: split the long work out into its own thread that sends asynchronous messages to the window.

Comment: You'll want to extract the work that causes the new window to take a while into the background thread, either done before the load or with a progress indicator as it's running. Loading a window and placing controls only shouldn't take a long time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't - there's only one GUI thread. If you need to do blocking work, that stuff has to go in a background thread.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run a separate message loop in the new thread using the Application class.

Comment: @Henk: Yes; I realize that it's bad advice.  However, the other answers already covered that.

Answer (score 1):

@SLaks This can be very useful if you are trying to launch a new window out of a console app. One option is to use `showDialog();` But then its difficult to close it.

If you use `Show()` and then an `Application.run()` (this is the nuts and bolts of using the  Application class to start a new message loop)

When you call `Application.Exit()` in your main console thread, then the app actually closes;

using `showDialog()`, you have to abort the thread, and then wait until the window gets some kind of input ie mouse over or focus. else it will hange on exit forever.