# Coded UI method in separate thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, coded-ui-tests

I have wrote a little application which can determine different properties of a control.
I use Coded UI methods.
So i have got a GUI where the control information's appeared.
I determine the control via the position of it.

```
UITestControl control = UITestControlFactory.FromPoint(new Point(X, Y));
```

After that, i ask the control specific properties with reflection.
All methods take about 5 second.

I would like to appear a loader message/control/window while computing in progress.
I found a suitable solution to it, i use BusyIndicator from Extended WPF Toolkit library.

I try to use Background worker class to implement my demand, but i get the next exception:
"The Coded UI Test is running in Single Thread Apartment (STA) mode of COM.  In this mode, all the playback calls should happen from the TestMethod thread only and UITestControl should not be shared across TestMethods."

My answer for it: OK.

I try an other idea.
I use parametrized thread, where i set the state for apartment to STA, because of the above exception.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(*CODED_UI_SEARCH_METHOD*));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start(Object object);
```

But after of it, i got the same message against my set thread.

So, my question: how can i solve to run the identifying of control in an other thread while a message window/control inform the user about the process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I ask why the inspection takes 5 seconds?

Comment: After the inspection, i determine the control specific properties with reflection. Because for example radiobutton and combobox have different kinds of properties.

Comment: It seems very strange that that should take so long. Do you have a large number of controls? I feel like you might be trying to solve the wrong problem! Also, having a second UI thread is [generally accepted as a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5570154/1174169). If you're interested in pursuing solving the performance lag, please post your inspection code so we can have a look.

Comment: Also, my apologies. I'm not familiar with [Coded UI Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681(v=vs.100).aspx). Perhaps my advice is ill-informed.

Comment: It sounds like you're misusing Coded UI.

Comment: So, my application task is help collecting Coded UI information about controls.
When you scan a control you can require this properties.
For example their is a WinRadioButton type control. It has got Checked property,
but a WinComboBox type control has not got Checked property.
So that is why i use reflection. It is give me back only the valid and exist properties of a control.

Comment: After inspecting/collecting, these information appeared on a GUI in a grid.
Yes, it is an independent application which use Coded UI search/analyze methods to collect information.
(I collected and imported the dependencies, e.g.: DLL files).
There is two part: GUI and Coded UI. I would like to isolate the latter component because of the GUI.

I acknowledge, my usage of Coded UI, not a conventional way of this framework.